# Sharepoint 2010 to store or sync user credentials from Active Directory

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-2010, synchronization

Is there a way to enable SharePoint 2010 to store or sync user credential so that it can authenticates to it self. Then schedule a sync service to update user credentials.

This would help if there is a problem connecting to AD, users would still be able to enter the site.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard product.

Of course with enough code you could write your own system, but I think this will make it way more complex and less secure as you would make passwords decryptable in the AD, and you will have stored them in a second place where you will be responsible for your own security measures.

Is there a reason why your AD would be unreachable? Because there are other ways to make an AD high available which are much more cheaper to configure then creating a custom solution.